# Is having 10 employees for a pharmaceutical company an indicator that it is not a legit operation?

Tags: scams, stock-valuation

There was case recently where a particular company's stock price had increased from little above $3/share to about $10/share within a course of 10 days.

At the time the stock price was close to $10/share, Citron Research released a report on the company with the title "SEC Must Immediately Halt this Stock Promotion Scheme". This led the company share price to fall to around $6/share. Citron removed their report the following day (it can still be found [here](https://www.docdroid.net/f6HwibU/cydy-sec-must-immediately-halt-this-stock-promotion-scheme-pdf)).

One of the negative things about the company stated in that report is (emphasis added),

> This is a $5 billion market cap company **with 10 employees** who
> claims to have the cure for COVID

Looking at the stock prices on [this company](https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/CYDY) it seems to have been around since before 2008.

Question I wanted to ask is, are there precedents on other pharmaceutical companies that were operated by a handful of employees and that turned out to be valuable?

Comment: Question in the body does not match the question in the title.

Answer (score 4):

Number of employees doesn't mean much. I could have 10 employees and contract out work done by thousands of others generating billions in revenue. That said, it apparently doesn't take that many people to work on a drug, I'm familiar with a couple small pharmaceutical companies with a low number of employees that have one or two drugs they are working on for years at a time. I wouldn't base investing decisions on number of employees.